# Python - Remove Key/Value element from list and return new list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have been reading a few other SO articles and understand bits and pieces of what I am trying to accomplish, but I have yet to settle on an answer that encompasses my requirements.

I know how to remove a single item from a simple list like [1,2,3,4], but I have a more complex list, where the order/contents are not predictable, that I am trying to remove an element from:

```
list = [{u'role': u'OWNER', u'userByEmail': u'test1@email.com'}, {u'specialGroup': u'projectWriters', u'role': u'READER'}, {u'specialGroup': u'projectOwners', u'role': u'READER'}, {u'specialGroup': u'projectReaders', u'role': u'READER'}, {u'role': u'READER', u'userByEmail': u'test2@email.com'}, {u'view': {u'projectId': u'project-01', u'tableId': u'testing_tbl_2', u'datasetId': u'test2'}}, {u'view': {u'projectId': u'project-01', u'tableId': u'testing_tbl_3', u'datasetId': u'dtest2'}}, {u'view': {u'projectId': u'project-01', u'tableId': u'view1', u'datasetId': u'test2'}}]
```

I need to remove:

```
{u'role': u'READER', u'userByEmail': u'test1@email.com'}
```

and return the new list without that key/value element present. I can do something like this (I would prefer this format) but this only returns the key/value element that the filter is looking for.

```
>>> filter(lambda row: row.has_key('userByEmail') and row['userByEmail'] == 'test1@email.com', list)
[{u'role': u'OWNER', u'userByEmail': u'test1@email.com'}]
```

How do I remove the element from the list and then print out the new list with the filtered element missing?

Comment: So, you should use `filter` with a `lambda` that does exactly the opposite.

Comment: The predicate you give to filter decides *what to keep*. Just negate it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert the condition to

```
not (...)
```

so

```
filter(lambda row: row.has_key('userByEmail') and row['userByEmail'] == 'test1@email.com', list)
```

becomes

```
filter(lambda row: not (row.has_key('userByEmail') and row['userByEmail'] == 'test1@email.com'), list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe with `next()`:

```
list.remove(next(obj for obj in list if obj == {u'role': u'READER', u'userByEmail': u'test1@email.com'}))
```